# Acts as votable javascript vote button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a gem called [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) to make my model votable.

Currently everything is working.

But every time someone votes for a post, the page has to refresh. How do I get the voting to work without the page refreshing. Is there a simple javascript I can add?

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
def vote
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @post.liked_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back }
  end
end
```

Here is what I have in my view:

```
 <%= link_to “like post", like_post_path(@post), method: :put %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A very simple version might look like this:

Ruby

```
def vote
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @post.liked_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back }
    format.json { render json: { count: @post.liked_count } }
  end
end
```

Html

```
<%= link_to 'like', vote_path(@post), class: 'vote', remote: true, data: { type: :json } %>
```

JS

```
$('.vote')
  .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
  .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
  .on('ajax:error', function () { $(this).after('<div class="error">There was an issue.</div>'); })
  .on('ajax:success', function (data) { $(this).html(data.count); });
```

This is a very rudimentary version that shows the basic approach, but it has some obvious pitfalls:

- There is no way to "unvote"
- A "loading" indicator isn't great UX; with JS we can always show the user's current state and deal with syncing to the server in the background
- Any HTML cacheing in the view will blow this up

Comment: Why can we.leave out format.js?. How does his work? I can't seem to find a straight answer.on how respond http://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/top-10-mistakes-that-rails-programmers-makeo works for each case.

Comment: format.js would deal with a request for JavaScript. So you could have the action respond with actual code to be run when it is loaded. I'm doing format.json, which means the action is going to return a JSON formatted string.

Comment: how does that json get handled? What are the steps, and what triggers them? you still have js code, and it still gets run.

Comment: I mark the vote link as "remote" in the link_to helper. Rail's default JS will kick in, and submit that link using ajax. As the ajax is processed, it triggers different events on the link as it goes through it's life cycle (ajax:send, ajax:complete, ajax:success). The ajax:success event includes the data sent down from the server; the last line above uses the data to update the UI.

Comment: Here, I wrote up an example to helpfully explain how this works a little bit better: http://jsfiddle.net/6XY8h/

Comment: That's really helpful. So what actually makes this happen is `remote: true` plus `respond_to.json`? Rails implicitly calls a js equivalent to what you wrote when those two conditions are met?

Comment: I'm still confused: in your original answer, you say you need javascript. Is that in the file named `the_controller_action.js`? in the views template? In the example, I'm not sure if it's all one javascript file or more, and what they're named or where they are in the directory tree. Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned faking a counter. Is that implying we can inset custom javascript behavior within this "fake" javascript? I thought the "fake" javascript was just just to show explicitly waht rails does in the background implicitly.

Comment: I can follow all the procedural logic in your example, but it's things like location, what's customizable, and how/why rails does this. So what if you do this, but also have a `respond_to.js`? `respond_to.js` serves up the js template in the views folder... so if you meant to put the code in a `the_controller_action.js` file, then there would be a conflict with the behavior of `respond_to.js` and `respond_to.json`, no?

Comment: Sorry for the verbosity, but I'm not sure how to explain this correctly, so I'm trying to attack it from multiple angles. Basically, a lot of the stuff that weren't mentioned in your valuable explanation is what I had questions on.

Comment: the fake stuff just happens automatically with rails, and we don't have to put it anywhere, correct? Everything after the fake stuff... where does it go?

Comment: I'd package it into my assets, so something like: `app/assets/javascripts/vote_widget.js`. And then in `application.js`, `//= require vote_widget`. You can ignore the fake counter; in real life, the server will respond with a JSON object, that includes the real number of votes to display.

Comment: As to why to do it this way? This is a good read: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs

Comment: what is the file name/location that you are recommending to put the javascript code that is not "fake" in your example?

Comment: My code would go into `app/assets/javascripts/vote_widget.js`. In `application.js` I would include it using the asset pipeline. I would add `application.js` to the bottom of my layout.

Comment: Just came across this now and am using Rails 3.2.18...everything is working apart from the content replacement with the updated count. I keep getting "net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" errors. When I manually refresh, the count has increased as expected. I can't figure out how to get this working properly. Annoying.

Comment: I got this all figured out (I had to comment out the format.html line), but now the problem is that data.count is undefined. I'm returning format.json { render json: { count: @album.get_upvotes.size } } (which I use in the view to properly display the number of upvotes) and it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah. I finally see the confusion here, the UJS handlers default remote links to use the `.js` format by default, I had that overridden to use `.json`. Updating my example with a fix.

Answer (score 6):

Simple. Take away your respond block:

```
def vote
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @post.liked_by current_user
end
```

and make your button remote:

```
<%= link_to “like post", like_post_path(@post), method: :put, remote: true %>
```

If you would like to have a script run when a person votes to pop up a message or something, create a file `vote.js.erb` (by rails naming convention) and put it in the view folder.
You can put javascript in there that will run when the controller action is accessed.

PS, are you sure the path `like_post_path` points to your `vote` controller?

Comment: You can keep the respond block, and add a `format.js` line as well, right? Then it would work whether the user has JavaScript or not.

Comment: Yeah you can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails provides [Ajax helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#built-in-helpers) for this.
For example:

```
<%= link_to “like post", like_post_path(@post), method: :put, remote: true %>
```

But then you will need to update the vote counter manually with JavaScript.

Comment: Bwhen is it put and when is it post? The first vote will be a create (post), but subsequent votes will be updates or unvtes. How do you ensure the method is right for all the cases? Use the .html method in JavaScript? Is there a cleaner way?